# Product of tangents when angles are in AP

Tags: trigonometry

$$\displaystyle \tan\bigg(\frac{\pi}{25}\bigg)\cdot \tan\bigg(\frac{2\pi}{25}\bigg)\cdot \tan\bigg(\frac{3\pi}{25}\bigg)\cdots\cdots \tan\bigg(\frac{12\pi}{25}\bigg)$$
I know how to evaluate this using Complex numbers and then using Viete's theorem.
Is there a way that this can be found out only using Trigonometry?

Comment: [Duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2780301/find-value-of-tan-big-frac-pi25-big-cdot-tan-big-frac2-pi25-big-c)

Comment: @SathvikAcharya Are you suggesting me to just post my comment on the original question?

Comment: No, it adds value to the question by providing solutions already presented by users on the site.

Comment: In theory, you could repeatedly apply the tan addition formula and hope it simplifies nicely.

Comment: Not sure if this helps, but: Using $\cos(x)=\sin\left(\frac\pi2-x\right),$ $$\tan \frac{n\pi}{25}=\frac{\sin\frac{n\pi}{25}}{\sin\frac{(25-2n)\pi}{50}}$$

So the product is $$\prod_{n=1}^{24} \left(\sin\frac{n\pi}{50}\right)^{(-1)^n}$$

Comment: It seems like you might be able to use Chebyshev polynomials. That might be what the Vieta argument is hiding. But it won’t be any easier than Vieta.

Comment: There is also a similar question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3556048/proving-that-prod-k-1n-tan-left-frac-pi-k2n1-right-sqrt2n1-us), [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4072769/evaluating-prod-k-1m-tan-frack-pi2m1) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1311717/simplify-prod-k-15-tan-frack-pi11-and-sum-k-15-tan2-frack-pi1).

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/346368/sum-of-tangent-functions-where-arguments-are-in-specific-arithmetic-series